# How to implement LinkedList in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linked-list, entity-framework-core

I want to persist a linked list of objects using in my ASP.Net Core application. For simplicity, I'll use blog and comments; although the real context is much more complex.

I scaffolded two tables, and changed `ICollection<Comment>` to `LinkedList<Comment>`. However, if I create an initial migration and apply to an empty database, I don't get anything "linked" in the database (no next or previous). Also, if I seed the data, and then do something like this:

```
var comments = _context.blogs.First().Comments
```

I get `null`. If I leave `public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments`, I get the `IEnumerable` just fine.

I tried to use `LinkedList<LinkedListNode<Comment>>` instead, and it works nice unless I try to create a migration. Getting an error

> No suitable constructor found for entity type 'LinkedListNode'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'value' in 'LinkedListNode(Comment value)'; cannot bind 'list', 'value' in 'LinkedListNode(LinkedList list, Comment value)'.

I couldn't find any guidance how to implement LinkedList in C#/.NET Core (obviously, I can do it manually, having `next` and `prev` fields - but I would very much prefer to use framework capabilities, if possible!)

Comment: To my knowledge there is no standard framework approach for this (i could be wrong), you will seemingly have to manage it your self

Comment: Thank you. Obviously, I hoped for a different answer; but it's good to know that I didn't miss something obvious :)

Comment: You could override save changes, or *gasp* create a server side trigger (though both these seems fraught with issues)

Comment: You might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033924/creating-a-double-linked-list-in-entity-framework . I am pretty sure you can accomplish this, you just have to create the model properly. Perhaps you could post the model and context code here and we could point out your problems.

Comment: Thanks, @GlennSills. I think you misunderstood the question. I *don't* have a problem designing Linked List manually. I didn't *want* to. I want to use .NET built-in `LinkedList` and (possibly) `LinkedListNode` classes. The post that you linked to doesn't mention any of these. It looks like what I want to do is **not** possible - so I already did it manually. NOTE: one of the answers mentions `LinkedListNode` class, but it looks like poster's custom class; obscuring framework class. Something that I **definitely** don't want to do

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In general EF doesn't come with built in models, you need to design your own models.  When you get right down to it, that's what object relational mapping is for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about MS SQL server, but the whole next and prev parts in mysql won't work because you can't map the keys it would require to track the fields properly because each link has to have an id in a database to link to. only thing I know of would be create the next/prev yourself and use some custom data persistence or data annotations. but the foreign key constraints I'm pretty sure on any relational database will prevent you from auto persisting those types of fields. reason being tracking deletes, inserts etc would be a nightmare because if you remove the middle of the chain, then the database has to try and guess where to link the ends to

Comment: Thanks. It would be much easier to read and understand what you are trying to say if you had sentences that are more concise. In any event, while I love MySQL, I am having trouble correlating your comment to my question.